# SocketException : No such host is known

Tags: .net, mysql, vb.net, exception

I want to connect to mysql database from my asp page.So for that as per what my hosting providers told i used the connection string where server is given as "localhost:3309"

```
Dim myConnection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost:3309; user id=TID; password=TPWD; database=TDB; pooling=false;")

Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT * from Device_Data"

Dim myDataAdapter As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(strSQL, myConnection)
Dim myDataSet As DataSet = New DataSet()
myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Device_Data")

MySQLDataGrid.DataSource = myDataSet
MySQLDataGrid.DataBind()
```

But when i run this page i got this error

```
[SocketException (0x2af9): No such host is known]
System.Net.Dns.GetAddrInfo(String name) +6134386
System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6) +136
System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(String hostNameOrAddress) +109
MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetDnsHostEntry(String hostname) +123

[Exception: Call to GetHostEntry failed after 00:00:02.2499197 while querying for hostname 'localhost:3309': SocketErrorCode=HostNotFound, ErrorCode=11001, NativeErrorCode=11001.]
MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetDnsHostEntry(String hostname) +405
MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetStream(UInt32 timeout) +457
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open() +215

[MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.]
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open() +283
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings) +51
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() +362
System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +123
System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +319
System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable) +92
show.form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in 
System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +146
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207
```

So is this the server issue?? If yes then what should they do to resolve this issue? When contacted the server guys they are saying this is my coding issue.. Are they right?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[The correct connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql) for MySQL ADO.NET Connector is

```
Server=localhost;Port=3309;Database=Test;Uid=username;Pwd=password;
```

Comment: it helped me when i try to connect E.F to MySql. thanks

Answer (score 3):

try `server=localhost; port=3309`