# Server Error in '/' Application [No such host is known]

Tags: asp.net, mysql

**No such host is known**

**Description**: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details**: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is known

**Source Error:**

```
Line 21:         MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(MyConStrings);
Line 22:         MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT id ,name  FROM asd_table Where weekno      ='"+getWeek+"';", conn);
Line 23:         conn.Open(); //red highlight here
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
   [SocketException (0x2af9): No such host is known]
   System.Net.Dns.GetAddrInfo(String name) +6603642
   System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6) +106
   System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(String hostNameOrAddress) +109
   MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.CreateStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings, Boolean unix) +64
   MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings) +38
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open() +55

[MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.]
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open() +151
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open() +22
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings) +208
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection() +261
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver() +93
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection() +65
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() +625
   play_db_mysql.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\hosting\folder1\html\web\website\asd_db_mysql.aspx.cs:23
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772
```

been stuck with this like forever, i have my sql db hosted in godaddy and this is my connection string that ive used in my .cs file

```
String MyConStrings = "SERVER=serverurl;" +
    "DATABASE=dbname;" +
    "UID=username;" +
    "PASSWORD=passsword;";
```

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SocketException : No such host is known](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970177/socketexception-no-such-host-is-known)

Comment: @CodeCaster: ive tried setting it in this format as well Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=Test;Uid=username;Pwd=password; with the port number as specified by godaddy, still no go

Comment: [see their help](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5111/why-is-wordpress-unable-to-connect-to-my-database-during-install). The database is not on `localhost`.

Comment: yeah i mean ofc ive set the server to the ip or the url that ive been assigned to by them for the db, i pointed out that i used that particular format that you linked me to.

Comment: Well the error you received claims otherwise: the webserver cannot find the host `host` with the name you specified at `Server=host` in your connection string. Are you sure you are configuring the correct hostname? Can you try it on IP address? Perhaps your version of `MySQLConnection` doesn't understand the `Server=host` part of your connection string, can you try it with `Data Source=host`?

Comment: @CodeCaster weird i just tried using the ip and it worked, thanks.

Comment: You might want to inform GoDaddy about that, maybe they're having DNS issues on your server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to see if database serverurl is accessible from web-server where the site is hosted. Looking at the error it seems either DB server is not accessible or there is problem in DNS lookup.

Try to ping DB server through command prompt on web-server.

For possible MySQL connections strings refer to http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/